# Call an existing odoo 9 pos popup

Tags: jquery, odoo-9, point-of-sale

In version 9.0c of odoo, specifically in the point of sale.

How can I call an existing popup? I understand that the way to do this process is very different with version 8.0c.

In 8.0c i use: self.pos_widget.screen_selector.show_popup("popup_name");

In 9.0 how i can call click_username?

Comment: would you let us know what you tried(Code)?

Comment: Hello. In the 8.0 version i use: self.pos.pos_widget.screen_selector.show_popup('popup_name'); But in the 9.0 i don't know how i can call a popup.

Comment: Update that in the question... It helps people sort out things faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can call base popup like this in odoo v9.

```
 this.gui.show_popup('confirm',{});
```

In the second argument, you can specify the title, body etc.

eg.

```
        this.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
            'title': _t('Destroy Current Order ?'),
            'body': _t('You will lose any data associated with the current order'),
            confirm: function(){
                self.pos.delete_current_order();
            },
        });
```